# append item in for loop

Tags: python, django

mysql db table XXX

```
id | a  |
---------
1  | 111|
2  | 222|
3  | 333|
```

I got query result from mysql database.

```
info = XXX.objects.filter(a = 111)
for item in info:
    item.update({b:111})
```

It makes error "XXX has no attribute 'update'
I want to append more key:value set into item.
How can I go it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django filter return the list of [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets) not dictionary so @Danfi's approach is right

```
info = XXX.objects.filter(a = 111) #return the list of QuerySet (objects)
for item in info:
    item.b = 111   # Object
    item.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

if your table has field b

```
XXX.objects.filter(a = 111).update(b=111)
```

or

```
info = XXX.objects.filter(a = 111)
for item in info:
    item.b = 111
    item.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

`item` is not a [mapping](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). If you want to set attributes on an object then just do so.

```
item.b = 111
```

Note that Django will not retain the change unless it is already a field in the model and you make sure to save `item`.